# Hello, It is legal to charge for installing Ubuntu to another person?

Tags: legal

It is legal to charge for installing Ubuntu to another person?

Comment: Yes it is, because you are charging for your time not the Ubuntu itself and as I know you can even sell a copy of any [free software](https://www.fsf.org/) ...

Comment: If it's a business, like a repair shop, it's perfectly OK. Installing Ubuntu can be considered a service. I'm not a lawyer, though, and this site is for technical advice only, not legal advice, so I'd say take advice with a grain of salt.

Comment: Yes. If they don't want to pay for your service they can do it for themselves

Comment: @Ravexina Well, selling a copy depends on license terms,too. If I recall correctly, GPL and MIT allow that. Apache license has patent clause, if I'm not mistaken, so selling that type of software might have legal implications

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy That might be true, but as I recall for a license to be compatible with FSF licenses it should have all those 4 freedoms which one lets you to [sell a copy](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.en.html). I might be wrong...

Comment: @Ravexina  Yep,  but as you said, it has to be  one of the licenses compatible with FSF.  So still depends on the licensing terms.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  You're not selling the software.  You're selling the act of installing the software.  They're two distinct things.  It's perfectly okay to sell an act of installation or maintenance of FOSS.  I morally wouldn't sell FOSS itself, but some licenses allow it.  Either way, selling the act of installing or repairing is always OK.  The act of selling FOSS may not be depending on license and modifications. (US)

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, Greetings from Argentina

Comment: Be warned that legal questions are technically out of bounds here.  I only answered, because I think it's not really a legal question.  It's the same as asking "Is it legal to use traceroute while I troubleshoot a network problem and charge for network diagnostic services".  I only really answered the no-brainer part.